# jQuery .offset() giving incorrect values

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working on an image uploading system where the user can resize & move the uploaded image around so only the part within a target area is kept (the black box), the image will have already been uploaded at this point and gets cropped based on the users input here.

I'm having a problem getting the correct value from the jQuery .offset() method, it seems to register the top value as being 184 but to my eye it looks incorrect and when I check it in Photoshop with a screenshot sure enough it is. This has been causing my issue for some time and I've searched a lot trying to find and answer to this to no avail. I'm starting to wonder if it's my understanding on the jQuery documentation which is at fault.

I've put a cut down version of the code which has the same problem below, the resize & dragging of the image has been removed as .offset() reports incorrect values from the moment it is displayed so I tried to remove as much of the code that wasn't required to replicate the problem as possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, what I'm basically trying to do is get the position of the img & .targetArea relative to the document to work out what part of the image should be cropped out.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title></title>

    <style type="text/css">
    #basic-modal-content{ display:none; }

    /* Overlay */
    #simplemodal-overlay{ background-color: black; }

    /* Container */
    #simplemodal-container{
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 4px solid white;
        background-color: rgb(31, 122, 207);
        color: white;
    }
        #simplemodal-container .simplemodal-data{ padding: 0; }

        #simplemodal-container #imageUploader div .targetArea{
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            border: 5px solid black;
            margin: 0;
            pointer-events: none;
            z-index:2;
        }

        #simplemodal-container #imageUploader div .uploadedImageContainer{
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: move;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="simplemodal-overlay" class="simplemodal-overlay" style="opacity: 0.5; height: 838px; width: 1707px; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 1001;"></div>

<div id="simplemodal-container" class="simplemodal-container" style="position: fixed; z-index: 1002; height: 796.1px; width: 1621.65px; left: 28.6796875px; top: 6.953125px;">
    <a class="modalCloseImg simplemodal-close" title="Close"></a>
    <div tabindex="-1" class="simplemodal-wrap" style="height: 100%; outline: 0px; width: 100%; overflow: visible;">
        <div id="imageUploader" class="simplemodal-data">
            <div id="imageUploadStep1">
                <h2>Image uploader</h2>

                <div class="targetArea" style="width: 640px; height: 480px; margin-top: -240px; margin-left: -320px;"></div>
                <div class="uploadedImageContainer ui-draggable" style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -235px; margin-left: -315px;">
                    <div class="ui-wrapper" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: auto; left: auto; margin: 0px;">
                        <img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3681/14261132661_36ab0bbf08_o.jpg" style="max-width: 640px; margin: 0px; resize: none; position: static; zoom: 1; display: block;" class="ui-resizable">
                        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
                        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
                        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
                        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="uploadImageButtons">
                    <a id="saveStepOne" class="buttonStyle buttonImage saveImage positive">Save image</a>
                    <a id="closeImageUploader" class="cancelUploadImage buttonStyle buttonImage stopImage negative">Cancel image</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure the view in your browser isn't zoomed in or out?

Comment: Could you add the javascript calls?

Comment: @stackunderflow Yep I checked that the browser isn't zoomed either in or out.

Comment: @GuyHughes I could try adding them but I don't think the JS calls are the problem as with only CSS the problem still exists, I've kind of worked out the problem. The .offset() value reported is what the browser shows in the dev tools however this still doesn't match the Photoshop measurement, I think it's something to do with the way browsers & Photoshop measure things, it's different somehow?

I can't really explain it much better as I don't understand it myself but may be resolution or viewport related?

Comment: depends on your system. I could imagine that some DPI Scaling (Windows) messes it up. btw, here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SvEHp/

Comment: @NeilNand yes the definitions of 'pixel' and 'point' vary...

Comment: @SebastianSchmid Thanks for the JSfiddle, I'll have a look into DPI scaling as I am working from a smallish laptop (13.1 inch screen) with a high resolution and running Windows 8.

Comment: @GuyHughes That's interesting to know, do you happen to know of any articles or such that I could read up more on that? Or what an appropriate term to Google would be? Aside from "DPI scaling" suggested by Sebastian I can't think of any others.